# Pedestrian Crossings For Entire City via OSMnx

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I am interested in extracting all pedestrian crossings (including marked and unmarked crosswalks) for an entire city, such as Chicago. Thus far the following code yields may of the crossings I want, but many seem left out, whereas I can see in OSM that they are mapped for the intersection in question. I cannot tell what is missing in my list that is omitting those crossings. I do understand that not every pedestrian crossing is mapped in OSM for Chicago, but I wonder how I can modify this code to ensure I'm capturing every pedestrian crossing that is a feature in OSM.

```
import osmnx as ox

# Set console logging to True
ox.settings.log_console = True

# Set useful tags for walking network
useful_tags = ox.settings.useful_tags_way + [
    'crossing', 'crossing:uncontrolled', 'crossing:zebra', 'crossing:marked',
    'crossing:traffic_signals', 'crossing:school', 'crossing:island',
    'crossing:refuge_island', 'crossing:island:central',
    'crossing:island:central:traffic_signals', 'crossing:island:central:marked',
    'crossing:island:central:zebra', 'crossing:unmarked', 'highway:crossing',
    'pedestrian'
]

ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True, useful_tags_way=useful_tags)

# Download the network with specified tags
G = ox.graph_from_place(query='Chicago, Illinois, USA', network_type='walk', simplify=False, retain_all=True)

# Identify and remove non-walk edges
non_walk = []
for u, v, k, d in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    is_walk = "walk" in d and d["walk"] == "designated"
    is_crossing = (
        d.get("highway") in ["crossing", "pedestrian"] or
        "crossing" in d or
        "crossing:uncontrolled" in d or
        "crossing:raised" in d or
        "crossing:speed_table" in d or
        "crossing:hump" in d or
        "crossing:zebra" in d or
        "crossing:marked" in d or
        "crossing:traffic_signals" in d or
        "crossing:school" in d or
        "crossing:island" in d or
        "crossing:refuge_island" in d or
        "crossing:island:central" in d or
        "crossing:island:central:traffic_signals" in d or
        "crossing:island:central:marked" in d or
        "crossing:island:central:zebra" in d or
        "crossing:unmarked" in d or
        "highway:crossing" in d or
        "pedestrian" in d
    )

    # Include pedestrian crossings at intersections without traffic signals
    is_intersection = "highway" in d and d["highway"] == "uncontrolled_intersection"
    if is_intersection and not is_crossing:
        is_crossing = True

    # Exclude pedestrian sidewalks
    is_sidewalk = "sidewalk" in d
    if not is_walk and not is_crossing and not is_sidewalk:
        non_walk.append((u, v, k))

G.remove_edges_from(non_walk)
G = ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(G)
G = ox.simplify_graph(G)

# Calculate and print total edge length
stats = ox.stats.basic_stats(G)
print("Total Edge Length:", stats["edge_length_total"])

# Plot the graph
ox.plot_graph(G, node_color="w", node_size=15, edge_color="b", edge_linewidth=0.5, figsize=(20, 20))
```

[What I want (intersections on the right), and what's missing (intersections on the left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJqWY.png)

I've tried the above code, and see in my result (and upon viewing the geopackage in another window) that some of the pedestrian crossings are missing even when I know they are in OSM for the intersection.

[OSMnx Graph of Pedestrian Crossings in Chicago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbizd.png)

Comment: Please provide a couple OSM IDs of missing crossings that you know are on OSM.

Comment: One example is the intersection of West Augusta Blvd and North Campbell Avenue. Within OSM, there are crossings marked, such as Node: 9934869727 (Location: 41.8993515, -87.6895066).

Crossing - Uncontrolled
Crossing:Island - No
Highway - Crossing
Tactile Paving - Yes

Answer (score 1):

You said that the node `9934869727` was missing from the OSMnx model but exists on OSM itself. However, your code appears to be capturing and modeling it just fine. If you check for its presence in your graph `G` throughout the code's execution, you can see exactly where you lose it:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True
ox.settings.useful_tags_way += [
    'crossing', 'crossing:uncontrolled', 'crossing:zebra', 'crossing:marked',
    'crossing:traffic_signals', 'crossing:school', 'crossing:island',
    'crossing:refuge_island', 'crossing:island:central',
    'crossing:island:central:traffic_signals', 'crossing:island:central:marked',
    'crossing:island:central:zebra', 'crossing:unmarked', 'highway:crossing',
    'pedestrian'
]

G = ox.graph_from_place(query='Chicago, Illinois, USA', network_type='walk', simplify=False, retain_all=True)

node = 9934869727
node in G  # True

non_walk = []
for u, v, k, d in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    is_walk = "walk" in d and d["walk"] == "designated"
    is_crossing = (
        d.get("highway") in ["crossing", "pedestrian"] or
        "crossing" in d or
        "crossing:uncontrolled" in d or
        "crossing:raised" in d or
        "crossing:speed_table" in d or
        "crossing:hump" in d or
        "crossing:zebra" in d or
        "crossing:marked" in d or
        "crossing:traffic_signals" in d or
        "crossing:school" in d or
        "crossing:island" in d or
        "crossing:refuge_island" in d or
        "crossing:island:central" in d or
        "crossing:island:central:traffic_signals" in d or
        "crossing:island:central:marked" in d or
        "crossing:island:central:zebra" in d or
        "crossing:unmarked" in d or
        "highway:crossing" in d or
        "pedestrian" in d
    )

    # Include pedestrian crossings at intersections without traffic signals
    is_intersection = "highway" in d and d["highway"] == "uncontrolled_intersection"
    if is_intersection and not is_crossing:
        is_crossing = True

    # Exclude pedestrian sidewalks
    is_sidewalk = "sidewalk" in d
    if not is_walk and not is_crossing and not is_sidewalk:
        non_walk.append((u, v, k))

G.remove_edges_from(non_walk)
node in G  # True

G = ox.utils_graph.remove_isolated_nodes(G)
node in G  # True

G2 = ox.simplify_graph(G)
node in G2  # False
```

Your filter followed by graph simplification is removing features you wish to retain. You can see what's happening if you load the graph in QGIS to explore it visually. This compares the graph right after the `graph_from_place` code (blue) to what remains right after the `remove_isolated_nodes` code (red):

[image: screenshot]

The part of the graph containing node `9934869727` remains a disconnected trivial ring (in red). When you simplify the graph, this trivial ring is removed by default. You could parameterize it differently:

```py
G3 = ox.simplify_graph(G, remove_rings=False)
node in G3  # True
```

So your node remains after simplification. But given the appearance of the graph, I'm not sure you're filtering it the way you intend to. Though I'm unsure of your use case and goals, so I cannot say for sure.

Either way, this is the answer as to why your node is missing. OSMnx is modeling everything correctly: you're just filtering out stuff around that node, resulting in a trivial ring that gets removed during simplification.

Comment: This is great - thanks for taking the time to dig into this.